# Want to add Keyboard input to my calculator. Also hide the mouse cursors?

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, calculator

I am new to c#. I built a simple calculator. But it does not have keyboard input. How to enable it?

1. I want to get 5 in the text box when number 5 s pressed from keyboard.
2. Also i want to hide mouse cursor in text field. Now when the application stars, mouse cursor appears in the text field.

This is my code:

```
namespace MyCalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //textBox1.Text = "0";


    }

    double num1=0, num2, result;
    string op;

    private void button_plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "") 
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        op = "+";

    }

    private void button_minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
             num1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        op = "-";

    }

    private void button_mul_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "") 
              num1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        op = "*";

    }

    private void button_div_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "") 
                 num1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        op = "/";

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "2";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "3";
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "4";
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "5";
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "6";
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "7";
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "8";
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "9";
    }

    private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
    }

    private void button00_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "00";
    }

    private void button_point_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ".";
    }

    private void button_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
    }

    private void button_result_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calculate(op);

    }

    public void calculate( string op)
    {
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        switch(op)
        {
            case "+" : result=num1+num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString(); break;
            case "-": result = num1 - num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString(); break;
            case "*": result = num1 * num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString(); break;
            case "/": result = num1 / num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString(); break;

        }
        num1 = 0; num2 = 0;            
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Font = new Font("Arial",12, FontStyle.Bold);
        textBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;


    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To capture keyboard `KeyDown` event you have to first enable `KeyPreview` of that form. Select the form and go to properties and set `KeyPreview = true`.

Use `KeyDown` event to capture keyboard events,

```
  private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.NumPad5))
            {
               //Assuming button5 will set the value 5
               button5.PerformClick();
            }
        }
```

`Hiding Cursor`

I assume you are expecting the same behaviour as Windows calculator. Rather than hiding the cursor simply you can disable the textbox. Set the textbox `Enabled = false`.

Comment: In addition, you could call the `Button.PerformClick` method in order to simulate the Button press each time a given key is pressed. Also note that you probably want to account for not only the `NumPad5` key but also the `D5` key. The same is true for the `Oemplus` and `Add` keys and so on.. .

Comment: Thanks a lot. How to do Button.PerformClick ? how to perform that function? About the text box, i want it to be enabled. Thats ok. i want to give keyboard input to numbers and operations like +,- etc.  "Error showed up":  ...."Error 1 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyCode' and no extension method 'KeyCode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Arjun\My Visual Studio\Projects\MyCalculator\MyCalculator\Form1.cs 166 19 MyCalculator
"

Comment: Assume you have 10 buttons representing number 0 - 10 in your calculator whenever user click specific button you may have some logic within that button click event. you can execute that click event of that button for key press of keyboard thats what PerformClick() does for you. button5.PerformClick(); is similar to directly clicking button5 in the form with mouse.